# Substituting variables in a string without the '+' operator

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, string, formatting

This question concerns Processing code.

I know that you can substitute a variable in a string by doing the following:

```
String words = "these words";
text("I want to substitute " + words + "!", textX, textY);
```

However, I was wondering if there's a way to do it like I am used to doing this in Python:

```
words = "these words";
print('I want to substitute %s!' % words);
```

I find this much more readable as the strings aren't as cut up with all types of operators and variables.

Comment: Yes, have a look at: `String.format("I want to substitute %s!", words);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.format` for that:

```
String formattedString = String.format("I want to substitute %s!", words);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) in Java. It does the `String.format()` internally, so you can write pretty much in the same way as Python (or any language with printf-like functionality).

```
String words = "these words";
System.out.printf("I want to substitute %s!", words);
```